# How can I create a point allocation system in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a point allocation system in AngularJS. I've managed to create a basic directive that adds DOM elements. These elements include a span that shows "0" points and buttons to increment and decrement. There is a total number of points available that can be used to allocate among 4 different categories.

*Directive*

```
angular.module('components', []).
  directive('addSkills', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        max: '=',
        min: '=',
        pointValue: '='
      },
      template: '<div>' +
                  '<span>{{scoreValue}}</span>' +
                  '<button ng-click="addPoints()" ng-disabled="pointValue >= max">+</button>' +
                  '<button ng-click="minusPoints()" ng-disabled="pointValue <= min">-</button>' +
                  '</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.addPoints = function() {
          scope.scoreValue += 1;
          scope.$parent.pointsAvailable -= 1;
        };
        scope.minusPoints = function() {
          scope.scoreValue -= 1;
          scope.$parent.pointsAvailable += 1;
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

*Controller*

```
angular.module('myControllers', []).
controller('skills', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $q) {
  $scope.pointsAvailable = 10; // Hardcoded here, but actually formulated
  $scope.skills = {};
  $scope.skills.strength = {
    points: 0,
    description: '...',
    // more properties
  };
  $scope.skills.speed = {
    points: 0,
    description: '...',
    // more properties
  };
  $scope.skills.intelligence = {
    points: 0,
    description: '...',
    // more properties
  };
});
```

*HTML*

```
// more html code above
<div class="skills">
  <h4>{{pointsAvailable}}</h4>
  <div class="skillRating">
    <label>Strength: </label>
    <div data-add-skills data-point-value="skills.strength.points" data-max="pointsAvailable" data-min="0"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="skillRating">
    <label>Speed: </label>
    <div data-add-skills data-point-value="skills.speed.points" data-max="pointsAvailable" data-min="0"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="skillRating">
    <label>Intelligence: </label>
    <div data-add-skills data-point-value="skill.intelligence.points" data-max="pointsAvailable" data-min="0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to accomplish is, as you add points to each skill $scope.pointsAvailable is diminished. Thus, if you add 3 strength points, you only have 7 left to distribute to the other skills.

I tried modifying "pointsAvailable" on click of the increment buttons, but that didn't work because when allocating points to one skill it maxed out at 5 points, disabling the increment buttons. With each increment it diminished "pointsAvailable" so I could not, say, allocate all 10 points to one skill.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a super simple version, showing you how you do not need to use a directive: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4768/

This essentially uses `ng-repeat` to expose the commonality between skills.

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Points available: {{pointsAvailable}}
   <div ng-repeat="skill in skills">
    <div class="skillRating">
        <label>{{skill.name}}</label>
        <div>
            <span>{{skill.score}}</span>
            <button ng-click="addPoints(skill)" ng-disabled="skill.score >= skill.max || pointsAvailable <= 0">+</button>
            <button ng-click="minusPoints(skill)" ng-disabled="skill.score <= skill.min">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.pointsAvailable = 10;

    $scope.skills = [
        { name: 'strength', score: 0, max: 8, min: 0 },
        { name: 'speed', score: 0, max: 10, min: 0 },
        { name: 'intelligence', score: 0, max: 5, min: 0 }
    ];

    $scope.addPoints = function(skill) {
        skill.score += 1;
        $scope.pointsAvailable -= 1;
    };

    $scope.minusPoints = function(skill) {
        skill.score -= 1;
        $scope.pointsAvailable += 1;
    };
}
```